# Apache Help for downloading

Tags: apache, tomcat, ubuntu, vmware

I can't download Apache on my Virtual machine  workstation and follow the commands but these errors shown to me , what to do ???

E: Couldn't find package Apache 2

Comment: I write these command's 
root@alaa-desktop:~# sudo apt-get install apache2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Couldn't find package Apache 2
root@alaa-desktop:~#

Comment: Hi, this question belong in [superuser](http://superuser.com/) rahter than stackoverflow. To see what type of question belong on this forum please read the [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help) page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you asked the question here I will try to help you by providing a link to the [ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1191120) on the subject.

Apparently a `apt-get update` could help you.

Good luck.